# How to turn on safe search using bind 9 without rpz

Tags: bind, google

is it possible to enable safe search using bind9 without rpz?

The point is I don't want to get nslookup results like this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY2Y4.jpg)

Because it shows that what is being accessed is forcesafesearch.google.com, not google.com

Can you help me, if my question is difficult to understand, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The [relevant documentation from Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/186669?hl=en&ref_topic=3425457) tells you how to do it:

> To force SafeSearch for your network, you’ll need to update your DNS configuration. Set the DNS entry for [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) (and any other Google country domains your users may use) to be a CNAME for forcesafesearch.google.com.

So you basically have to ensure that all `google.tld` is answered with cname `forcesafesearch.google.com`.

The easiest and most logical way to achieve that with Bind would be a rpz.